# Find value, cut row, and paste in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I want to find people with a specific value in one of the columns in my sheet, cut their row, and paste them in a specified tab. (Even better would be if I can search for specific words in the cells of one of the columns since there are fiscal years involved that I don't want to fix annually.)

Sheet1
[image]

I'm looking for anyone who has "FD.Matching Gifts FY22" in column D. Or just the words Matching Gift. I want to cut those rows and paste them in my Matching tab, then delete the empty row.

I tried this, which I know wouldn't get me everything I want but it would have been a start:

```vb
Sub CopyMatching()

Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim Status As Range
Dim PasteCell As Range

Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("D2:D1000")
For Each Status In StatusCol

    If Sheet2.Range("A2") = "" Then
        Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("A2")
    Else
        Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(x1Down).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
    
    If Status = "FD.Matching Gifts FY22" Then Status.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 24).Copy PasteCell

Next Status

End Sub
```

The error here being

> "Application-defined or object defined error"

Then I found this but I don't think I put the pieces in the right places:

```vb
Sub MoveMatchRows()
  MoveRows "FD.MatchingGifts FY22"
End Sub

Sub MoveRows(Unit As String)
  With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter  ' switch filtering on or clear previous filter
    .AutoFilter 4, appeal_desc  ' filter so that only rows with "NTS" or whichever unit is passed in, are visible
    If .Columns(4).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Count = 4 Then
      ' none found
      MsgBox "No " & appeal_desc & " rows found"
    Else
      ' With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible)
        ' now dealing with the data only, not the headings
        .Copy
        ' paste the data to the row after the last used row in new sheet for the unit
        Sheets(appeal_desc & " New").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlAll
        .EntireRow.Delete   ' remove the copied rows
      End
    End If
    .AutoFilter ' remove the filter
  End With
End Sub
```

This error was

> "script out of range"

Answer (score 0):

### Move Criteria Rows to Another Worksheet

**The Solution (`AutoFilter`)**

- It is assumed that the data is in a table (one row of headers, not necessarily an `Excel table`), that it is contiguous (no empty rows or columns), and that it starts in cell `A1`.
- If you only need the first 24 columns you can do one of the following:

  ```
  Set srg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 24)
  Set srg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("A:X")
  ```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MoveMatchingDataRows()
    
    Const Title As String = "Move Data Rows"
    Const scCol As Long = 4
    Const dCol As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "FD.Matching Gifts FY22"
    
    ' Remove any previous filters.
    If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    
    ' Filter.
    Dim srg As Range ' Source Range (Headers and Data)
    Set srg = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    srg.AutoFilter scCol, Criteria
    
    ' Count the number of matches.
    Dim sdrg As Range ' Source Data Range (Without Headers)
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    Dim sdccrg As Range ' Source Data Criteria Column Range
    Set sdccrg = sdrg.Columns(scCol)
    Dim drCount As Long ' Destination Rows Count (Matches Count)
    drCount = Application.Subtotal(103, sdccrg)
    
    ' Move if there are matches.
    
    If drCount > 0 Then ' matches found
        
        Dim sdfrrg As Range ' Source Data Filtered Rows Range
        Set sdfrrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Dim dCell As Range ' Destination Cell
        Set dCell = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, dCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        With sdfrrg
            
            .Copy dCell
            
            ' Either delete the entire worksheet rows...
            '.EntireColumn.Delete
            
            ' ... or remove filter to prevent...
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
            ' ... deleting the entire worksheet rows leaving possible data
            ' to the right (after the empty column) intact.
            .Delete xlShiftUp
        
        End With
    
    Else ' no matches
        
        Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
   
    End If
        
    ' Inform the user.
    Select Case drCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No matches found. No action taken.", vbExclamation, Title
    Case 1
        MsgBox "Found one match.", vbInformation, Title
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Found " & drCount & " matches.", vbInformation, Title
    End Select

End Sub
```

**A Quick Fix (Loop)**

- You cannot loop from top to bottom in this way, because if there are consecutive rows containing the criteria, only the first row will be moved to leave the second row in place. You could use a `For...Next` loop and manipulate the counter variable accordingly but it is slow and just doesn't feel right.
- The problem in the following solution is that since we're looping from bottom to top (`For r = CopyLastRow To CopyFirstRow Step -1`), the data is copied upside down (it's only 'good' for deleting) and that it is not efficient (slow).
- An improvement would be to use `Application.Union` i.e. to loop from top to bottom, combining each matching cell into a range and then copying and deleting this range in one go (per action). I would have written it, but there are many examples on `SO` (e.g. [Union](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5Dunion), [GetCombinedRange](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bvba%5d%20GetCombinedRange)). Anyways, `AutoFilter` provides the most efficient way.

```vb
Sub CopyMatching()

    Const CopyFirstRow As Long = 2

    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    CopyLastRow = Sheet1.Range("D" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim PasteLastRow As Long
    PasteLastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    Set PasteCell = Sheet2.Range("A" & PasteLastRow).Offset(1, 0)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim CopyCell As Range
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = CopyLastRow To CopyFirstRow Step -1
        Set CopyCell = Sheet1.Range("D" & r)
        If CopyCell.Value = "FD.Matching Gifts FY22" Then
            With CopyCell.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 24)
                .Copy PasteCell
                .Delete
            End With
            Set PasteCell = PasteCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to express my most sincere thanks for your help. This worked very well. I expanded on it to do the same with other columns in my spreadsheet, some with a range of values. I'm sure it doesn't seem like much, but this will go far for me. Thank you.

Comment: I have a late follow-up: What if I'm looking for more than one criterion in a column? Ex: if column C could have a value of Undefined, Defined, Undesignated, or blank and I was looking for Undefined and Undesignated how would I get at that with what you used above?
I've tried Criteria1 = "Undefined", Criteria2 = "Undesignated", I've tried Array, I've tried "Or". I know I don't have to make a separate Macro. The info comes from the same sheet, and the same column, and it will be moved to the same tab I just haven't been able to figure out how to pluck out anyone with Undefined or Undesignated.

Comment: Have you tried `... Criteria1:=Array("Undefined", "Defined", "Undesignated", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues`? It's for multiple items. For exactly two items, you can alternatively use `... Criteria1:="=Undefined", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Undesignated"`. This has a ton of options and is best studied by using the `Macro-Recorder`. Try the various date filtering options and see what will be recorded.

Comment: I must be putting them together with the other info incorrectly, because those are some of the things I've tried.
Const Title As String = "Move Data Rows"
    Const scCol As Long = 16
    Const dCol As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "Undefined"

I've cobbled that "Const Criteria As String..." all kinds of ways, but it just won't go

Comment: Am I supposed to change the way I define the constants in the beginning?

    Const Title As String = "Move Data Rows"
    Const scCol As Long = 16
    Const dCol As Long = 1
    Const Criteria As String = "Undefined"